# Terraform for_each + tuple as multi-dimensional array

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a locals file to describe different parameters, for different environments e.g.

`parameters.tf`:

```
locals {
  env = {
    dev1 = {
     ...
      natgw_route_table_id           = "rtb-048....."
      transit_gateway_route_table_id = "tgw-rtb-05cc..."
      transit_gateway_id             = "tgw-087..."
      ec2_route_table_id             = "rtb-059..."
      ec2routes_ngw = {
        f1 = {
          destination_cidr = "10.12.13.14/24"\
          nat_gateway_id                = "nat-02a..." 
          transit_gateway_attachment_id = "tgw-attach-0f07..."
        }
        f2 = {
          destination_cidr = "10.12.13.15/32"
          nat_gateway_id   = "nat-0a6c..." 
          transit_gateway_attachment_id = "tgw-attach-028"
        }
     
      }
    }
    ...
    prod = {
       natgw_route_table_id           = "rtb-0be..."
      transit_gateway_route_table_id = "tgw-rtb-0ab7..."
      transit_gateway_id             = "tgw-00dfa..."
      ec2_route_table_id             = ["rtb-0de4...", "rtb-070a9...", "rtb-044a...", "rtb-0c8a..."]
      ec2routes_ngw = {
        f1 = {
            destination_cidr = "10.10.11.12/24"
            nat_gateway_id                = ["nat-09af...", "nat-042b...", "nat-078e...", "nat-0cd2c..."] 
            transit_gateway_attachment_id = "tgw-attach-0ed5025f6fc1731f7"
        }
      }
   }
  }
}
```

As you can see, for an environment called dev1 we have a single subnet to a single nat gateway.
This is easily solved with a resource like:

```
resource "aws_route" "natgw" {
  for_each               = { for k, v in local.workspace["ec2routes_ngw"] : k => v if(local.workspace["releaseStage"] != "prod")}
  route_table_id         = local.workspace["ec2_route_table_id"]
  destination_cidr_block = each.value.destination_cidr
  nat_gateway_id         = each.value.nat_gateway_id
}
```

However, for `prod` and potentially others we have a route table for each AZ Subnet with its respective NAT Gateway.

Now, I could hack this to work but I would prefer to do this a little more elegantly.

I found some similar examples using `for_each` with a flattened locals file. I don't mind having a separate resource for those `prod` type environments but would prefer to not hardcode it.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that this is your data structure? So once `ec2_route_table_id`and `nat_gateway_id`  are strings, then in prod they are a list? In other words, there is no consistency in your data structures?

Comment: agreeing on your data structure being inconsistent. Unfolding a such complex data structure in terraform involves a lot of remapping to get the access into the structure right for each and every resource you want to create out of it.. most likely involving refactoring the structure again using functions like `setproduct()` or `zipmap()` to get it right for creating resources with `for_each` later on.. we do a lot of those in our vpc module: https://github.com/mineiros-io/terraform-aws-vpc

Comment: Well, it's a pseudo data structure. Even if I format the `nat_gateway_id` as a list with one element for consistency sake, I do not know how to unfold it to create the appropriate resources.

Comment: There's a worked example for a situation similar to this in [Flattening nested structures for `for_each`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/flatten.html#flattening-nested-structures-for-for_each). If that was one of the examples you already saw, it'd help if you could show what you tried and what happened, or include in your question any specific concerns you had after referring to that example.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing the data structure, which made the whole problem easier to tackle. Thanks for all the help.